# Google apps email : forwarding to master act, how to reply fro original account address?

Tags: email, google-apps

I'm setting up Google Apps for the first time and I'm forwarding different email address to a master account address and applying different filters/labels to sort everything. Whenever I reply to an email that came in forwarded from another address my master account address is used to reply.

Any ideas how to change this so the original address the email was sent to, which was forwarded to my master account, would be the reply address?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you master account, you have to go your **email settings**, click the "**Accounts and Import**" tab. Then on the "**Send mail as**" section, click the link to include more accounts and follow the steps. Do this for all desired emails address you own.

Then, there's a radio button selection bellow it "**When replying to a message:**", select the
"**Reply from the same address the message was sent to**".

This should do it!